# Html_Helptool.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, html

Is there any simple way to improve this revamped code from [an earlier version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175591/html-help-tool-displays-basic-html-tag-uses/175595?noredirect=1#comment333241_175595)? I am looking for improvements that are SIMPLE, not more that post-advanced please.

```
import time
import os, signal

#Username = '_'

A = '''

<!DOCTYPE html> is the declaration tag for a standard HTML
document. This is used to tell the browser what kind of HTML document
it is.

'''
a = '''

<p> This tag defines a PARAGRAPH. These are highly customisable
in CSS, and can be used in any HTML version. There are variations
of this tag, such as:

<p1>
<p2>
<p3>
<p4>
<p5>
<p6>

and so on..

'''
B = '''

<h> This tag defines a HEADER. These, like PARAGRAPHS (see <p>),
are highly custonizable in CSS, and, like PARAGRAPHS, can be used
in any HTML version. There are variations of this tag, such as:

<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>

and so on..

'''
b = '''

<a> This tag defines a HYPERLINK. This can be used to turn ANY block
or peice of text into a clickable link. This has a variety of uses, such as:

Redirection
Buttons
Drop down menus
Navigations bars

and many more.

A hyperlink's syntax is as shows:

<a href = "www.LINK.com"  target = "(_blank, _parent, _self, and _top are
your options)" type = "(specify the type of linked document.)"></a>

The closing tag is nessesary for this to work with your given parameters.

'''
C = '''

<div> This tag defines a DIVIDED BLOCK where you can store content,
such as pictures, videos, buttons, text, and just about anything you can
think of. This is mainly used for containing things such as:

Navigation bars
Buttons
The entire page (Formally known as "Wrapper")
ETC.

This DIV's syntax is as shows:

<div class = "(calls a certain CSS class)"></div>

The closing tag is nessesary for this to work with your given parameters.

'''
c = '''

<link> This tag will LINK (a) CSS file(s) to your HTML document. You can
LINK multiple CSS files to a single HTML document. You can LINK files
from Google, as well as your own .css files.

The LINK's syntax is as shows:

<link href = "FILENAME.css (OR) www.LINK.com" rel = "Stylesheet" type =
"text/css">

'''

print("This tool was made to help programmers, like myself,")
print("with HTML tags. It takes your input, say you typed")
print("<div>, it would give you an accurate description of")
print("that tag and a list of its uses.")
print("")
print("Guest users please login as 'Guest'")
print("")
print("This tool was made by Chase Barnes")
print("@Copyright 2017")
print("")
print("(Remember, type BASE tags -<p>- ONLY)")
print("")

while True:
    Username = input("Username: ")
    if Username == 'Guest':
        Username = 'Guest'
        break
    elif Username == '/admin061503':
        Username = "Admin Chase"
        Pass = input("Password: ")
        if Pass == 'Slenderman123':
            Username = 'Admin Chase'
            break
        else:
            print("")
            print("The Input is Incorrect")
            print("")
    else:
        print("")
        print("UNKNOWN USERNAME")
        print("")
        continue


print("")
print("Welcome, " + Username + "!")
print("")

def main():
    Input = input("TAG: ")
    if Input == '/exit':
        answerexit = input("Are you sure? ")
        if  answerexit == 'yes':
            print("")
            print("SHUTTING DOWN..")
            print("")
            time.sleep(2)
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
        elif answerexit == 'no':
            print("")
            print("SHUTDOWN ABORTED..")
            print("")
            main()
    elif Input == '':
        print("")
        print("Please enter a tag or command.")
        print("")
        main()
    elif Input == '<!DOCTYPE html>':
        print(A)
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif Input == '<p>':
        print(a)
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif Input == '<h>':
        print(B)
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif Input == '<a>':
        print(b)
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif Input == '<div>':
        print(C)
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    else:
        print("")
        print('''The tag or command you entered is Not Recognized of is not yet
supported by this tool.''')
        print("")
        main()

main()
```

PURPOSE (readme.txt):

> Hey, You! Hello there! This programs function is to give information
>   about HTML tags and their uss/functions.
>
> CHANGELOG:
>
> Version_1 (9/15/2017):
>
> ```
>   Login Feature added         Six tags are added:             <!DOCTYPE html>             <p>
>       <a>             <h>             <link>          <div>       Startup info added      Shutdown
> ```
>
> feature added (Does not shutdown your computer, just the file)        added
>   TWO users:            -Admin Chase            -Guest
>
> Users:
>
> ```
>   Username: Guest         Password:
>           Username: /admin061503      Password: *************
>
>    How To Use:
> ```
>
> DO NOT open in pythons command prompt, open through IDLE or Python shell (IDLE)
>
> Enter Username on startup, then password. (If set)
>
> After you are logged in, Enter a tag or command!
>
> List of all keywords:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <p>
> <h>   <a>     <div>   <link>  /exit       yes         no
> ```

Comment: What indentation?

Comment: And, also, I have a README.txt file inside the folder of this py file.

Comment: I put the contents of the readme inside of the question

Comment: Why does every line start with four spaces?

Comment: because before I posted the question, I had to indent it that much for it to register as code. That's what it said to do.

Answer (score 7):

## Variable naming

The names of the variables defined at the top of your script are meaningless and do not convey their purpose.

## Check for `__main__`

Enclose script code to be run within an

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    <code_here>
```

block, so that it does not run if the module is solely imported.

## PEP8

Read and implement [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

## Text files

You should consider putting the running "help" text into files (plain text, INI, JSON etc.) and reading them within your source code.

## Termination

Terminating the program by

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

seems cumbersome. Use `exit` or `sys.exit` instead.

Comment: I tried using `sys.exit()` and `exit()`, but It kept saying ("The program is still running, do you want to kill it?" and I want it to 'shutdown' like a computer does, without having to mess with that silly dialogue box, so that is why I used `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)`

Comment: @ChaseBarnes This seems like a separate issue you may consider discussing on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028151/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-the-program-is-still-running-are-you-sure-you-want-to

Answer (score 5):

Recursive calls to loop over the same code again and again are an anti-pattern. If you let the program open for too long, it will die off eventually with a recursion error. Instead, use a while loop:

```
def main():
    while True:
        tag = input("TAG: ")
        if tag == '/exit':
            answerexit = input("Are you sure? ")
            if  answerexit == 'yes':
                print("")
                print("SHUTTING DOWN..")
                print("")
                time.sleep(2)
                break
            elif answerexit == 'no':
                print("")
                print("SHUTDOWN ABORTED..")
                print("")
        else:
            handle_tag(tag)
            time.sleep(1)


def handle_tag(tag):
    # put all your `if`s in there
```

A second thing that I don't get is the whole username/password thing. It's not used anywhere... Ho, yes, you greet the user, I see little too no point with that.

Third, the "manual" part, that is printed upfront would be better as a module [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Then you could just:

```
print(__doc__)
```

Lastly, I would put the tags description into a dictionary, it will let you add stuff painlessly as you wouldn't have to add a new `if` each time.

```
TAGS = {
    '<p>': '''
...''',
    '<h>': '''
....''',
...
}


def handle_tag(tag):
    try:
        print(TAGS[tag])
    except KeyError:
        print('unknown tag', tag)
```

Comment: could you edit the entire code to show what you mean? I am lost.

Comment: @ChaseBarnes what part don't you get exactly? 1) remove username/passwords 2) use a dictionary 3) use a while loop (which I provided the code for)?

Comment: I don't get the dictionary. I am not going to remove the Username/Password function because I plan to have a good purpose for that. It's just not finished yet. And I implemented your `while True` loop! It works like a charm!